# Validation (HTML5): Element 'picture' is not supported - Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: asp.net, intellisense

Does anyone else have this problem? There's no actual issue with  in the browser, it's just irritating to not have any IntelliSense when it comes to using  in Visual Studio.

Edit: [Requested screenshot of validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzZ9E.png)

Comment: My VS 2017 shows perfect intellisense for picture tag. could you show us your markup.

Comment: Thanks. I've attached a screenshot of my markup.